# Wireless Communication with Electronics

Tags: wireless, arduino, electronics

I'm working in an Escape room, I have a pi as main brain of the thing using a nodejs server, but I want some small stuff away from the pi to talk to it wirelessly.  My first approach would be to have a second raspi sitting in the second device and talk via WiFi to the nodejs but it feels like an overkill from the electronics and from the budget point of view.

The secondary device will measure ultra simple electronics (like a digital input reaching certain value or a combination of small numbers of them). I can handle that stuff with logic gates or an arduino with not a problem. Now my options are:

- Another raspi (50€)
- arduino + WiFi shield (any ideas on the final real price tag?)
- arduino + RF transmitter + RF receiver at raspi side (any idea on the price tag and difficulty of coding?)
- arduitno + Bluetooth (again, no clue in the price nor effort it needs)
- other options ?
- What about raspi zero W? does it actually exists? there is nothing to bu purchased in Europe. (I'm located in Spain)

I'd like to add that I'm using raspi2 right now but moving to raspi 3 shouldn't be an option so Bluetooth can also be in the list.

Another option would be raspi zero W .. does someone know something about it? did not find a single distributor in Europe selling them (I'm located in Spain)

Any suggestions from experienced people before I waste my time ?

Comment: "talk to it wireless-ly" is not very specific. E.g. would 4KB/s with a couple of seconds of latency be OK?

Comment: Certainly you are able to comparison shop for prices yourself.

Comment: If you are moving this project to a Pi 3, why can't you use the Pi2 as described in your first bullet? All that would be needed is a cheap WiFI dongle. I don't know where you are looking for a Pi Zero W, but I have purchased several from thepihut.com and pimoroni.com

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev 4KB/s is Ok but the 2 seconds delay is too much. The remote device will only need to tell the pi when the puzzle was solved so somehow a single byte once every hour. But would be nice if  the pi answer to the correct assembly ASAP

Comment: @user2497 this is actually something I didn't think about. I have those pi2 for development but at some point I can use them and get Pi3 for dev.. about the PiZeroW both sites you mention have the single piZW out of stock and the weird expensive bundles they have add 8 £ for shipping making the thing 22£ not too interesting ...